# Types inside a function in Python. Why some gets updated but not others?

Tags: python, function

Why does calling several times in a row the following function:

```
a = []

def test(a,b):
    if b > 0:
        a.append(1)
        return a
```

with test(a,4), it enlarges the list a each time, but calling several times in a row the function:

```
a = 0

def test(a,b):
    if b > 0:
        a += 1
        return a
```

with test(a,4) returns 1 every single time instead of 1, 2, 3, etc.?

It looks like lists get updated by a function and retain their updated value even after the function finished to execute, while this behavior doesn't hold for integers (and I guess floats and several other types).

Comment: Because in one case you're explicitly updating one mutable list object, and in the other you're creating new immutable integer objects.

Comment: See this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28567293/7269282) for a good explanation of this behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Integers are immutable; lists are mutable. `a += 1` changes the value of `a` by reassigning the value it refers to. `a.append(1)` adds the value `1` to the list that `a` refers to, without changing the reference itself.

In your `test` function, `a` if a reference within the function's scope;  not the same reference as `a` in the global scope. However, when passing a mutable object, the reference remains the same; allowing for the object to be modified without the need to reassign the variable. In your function

```
def test(a, b):
    if b > 0:
        a += 1
        return a
```

The value of `a` is modified relative to `test`. To reassign the value globally, you need to perform that action in the global scope (or use the `global` keyword). So, instead of `test(a, 4)`, use `a = test(a, 4)` to reassign the value of `a`.